# Problema con Jetstrap: require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: jetstream

Al intentar instalar `Jestrap` (cambiar `Jetstream` a Boostrap):

```
composer require nascent-africa/jetstrap --dev
```

Aparece el siguiente error:

> *nascent-africa/jetstrap[1.0, ..., v1.3.1] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement*

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Intente cambiar la versión de PHP a 7.4 pero sigue el mismo error.